# div not loading when iterating data using map function

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="wrapper" >
                                   {
                    (true)
                                   ?
                    cart['products'].map(product => function () {
                    <div className="main">
                                  product
                     </div>
                       })
                                   :
                                   false
                                   }

                                </div>
```

when items are available it never iterates the products, event though it is not going to the else part either. How do I fix it?

even though I can see that items become available in `cart[products]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, it is parentheses? I mean

```
...

(cart && cart['products'] && !cartLoading)

...
```

Comment: No :/ It's the map thing it is not getting into

Comment: Another guess :) cart['products'].map(product => function () {
                    <div className="main">
                                  product
                     </div>
                       })

Comment: Well, to press Enter was not a good idea. I wonder, can I edit posts? Anyway, another guess is that you did not put "return" before div.

Comment: And "product => {" instead of your strange "product => function () {"

Comment: Hey, Thanks :)  cart['products'].map(product => {
                                        return ( ) }) worked

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. If this doesn't render, you should examine the values `cartLoading`, `cart` and `cart.products`.  Also verify that `cart.products` is a true Array, and not a plain object.

```
<div className="wrapper">
    {
        !cartLoading && cart && cart.products && cart.products.map(product => () =>
            <div className="main">
                ${product}
            </div>
        )
    }
</div>
```

Comment: P.S. - It doesn't look like you want that ternary operation in there at all, otherwise you will sometimes render the word "false". but, I didn't want to modify your logic in my answer

Comment: Thanks for your response Jeff but it still doesn't work. I don't get the element at all. I tried both of the expressions.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope that helps!

Comment: Checked. It's an array of objects. I have tried putting in true directly there.It still doesn't render. :/

Comment: You'll need to post your entire component, or at least your render(). Something is clearly wrong. This div... are you return'ing it inside of a render() ?

Comment: Mc : Hey, Thanks :) cart['products'].map(product => { return ( ) }) worked :)